# Is it possible to manipulate the SvgIcon with a tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Going to add an icon and the challenge is that I can't find where I can deactivate `<strong></strong>`. Is it possible to manipulate the icon with a tag? Library that is made is custom made.

```
<PlainButton
    onClick={showModal}
    title={modalTitle}
    aria-label={modalTitle}
    style={{ lineHeight: 1 }}
    disabled={!notAcces}>
    <SvgIcon.PreviewDocument width={19} height={19} />
</PlainButton>
```

In the picture the other icon is normal, and the previewDocument has the tag `<strong>`. Just want to make it normal.

[image]

Comment: If you are using it from material library in react, Then the font properties can help you. I am assuming that you use this library, as you have not mentioned it. Kindly check this docs : https://mui.com/material-ui/api/svg-icon/. If you are using a different library mention that in the Question as it will be helpful for other viewing this question.

Comment: If `SvgIcon.PreviewDocument` is a wrapper around MUI SvgIcon try adding `sx={{ fontWeight: 'normal' }}`

Comment: @SARANSURYA Using custom made library for our icon.

Comment: @NicholaiMørchRindarøy So if it is custom made, then you might need to check the options that you can pass into the Component, Can you show us how the component is rendered, If Its custom made, we can add parameters around that.